# Why there exists access violation when I am trying to push back to the vector?

Tags: c++

Hi I am new to C++ and Stackflow, I met a question in C++ access violation, when trying to push_back a pointer to the class.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    vector<A*> *children;
    A() {}
};

int main()
{
    A *a=new A();
    A *b=new A();
    a->children->push_back(b); // access violation
    return 0;
}
```

Are there anyone to solve the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vector<A*> *children;
```

`children` is a pointer to `vector`, not a `vector`. Hence `a->children->` dereferences uninitialized pointer, causing undefined behavior.

You may try

```
vector<A*> children;
....
a->children.push_back(b);
```

**P.S.** Please pay attention to the memory leaks caused by `new`s without `delete`s.